# pass worksheet as parameter and then utilize that parameter as a variable

Tags: excel, vba

Why am I receiving an object required error for `aSheet_Recon (MAIN)` There is a sheet titled `MAIN`. I did not declare `somesheet` anywhere else.

```
Sub aSheet_Recon(somesheet As Worksheet)

...
End Sub


Sub tester()

aSheet_Recon (MAIN)


End Sub
```

**Update from answers and new challenge**

How do I then utilize the worksheet parameter as a variable through the rest of the procedure. I receive a type mismatch error when variable `cA` attempts to reference the value `MAIN` which is the passed worksheet paramter.

```
Sub aSheet_Recon(sheetname As Worksheet)

        cName = "Fund ID"
        cA = Sheets(sheetname).Rows.Find(What:=UCase(cName), LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column

End Sub
```

Comment: Edited my answer for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do this:

```
Sub tester()
    dim ws as worksheet 'Creating a worksheet variable to pass
    set ws = Sheets("MAIN") 'Assigning the sheet you want to pass to this variable
    aSheet_Recon(ws) 'Sending the newly created WorkSheet variable containing your worksheet
End sub
```

`aSheet_Recon` needs a WorkSheet argument, and will not work unless that's exactly what you're sending it (not a worksheet's Name, codename, index, etc. But the worksheet itself).

EDIT:

In answer to your own edit, here is how to use the worksheet you receive as an argument:

```
Sub aSheet_Recon(sheetname As Worksheet)

        cName = "Fund ID"
        cA = sheetname.Rows.Find(What:=UCase(cName), LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column

End Sub
```

You can also write it like:

```
sheetname.Range("A1") = "Hello!"
```

As a matter of fact, 'sheetname' is considered like a Worksheet in itself, and NOT a sheet's name. For the sheet's name, you would write sheetname.Name:

```
msgbox sheetname.Name
```

Will return "MAIN"

Because of this, I suggest changing "sheetname" to "MySheet" or something less confusing.

Comment: Done. I would imagine it is better?

Comment: Good job with the explanation +1

Answer (score 3):

Sheets are not global objects (How would a sheet called "Dim" or "500 x Beef Supreme" be handled?); you need to fetch the Sheet from the Sheets collection:

```
aSheet_Recon Sheets("MAIN")
```

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me is to use the ActiveSheet method.  Something like this...

```
Sub tester()
      Worksheets("MAIN").Activate
      aSheet_Recon
End Sub

Sub aSheet_Recon()
      'MsgBox(ActiveSheet.Name)
      cName = "Fund ID"
      cA = ActiveSheet.Rows.Find(What:=UCase(cName)).Column
End Sub
```